# Simple application in Python using OpenCV for face

Tags: python, python-2.x, opencv

I have been working on a simple Python application for face recognition with OpenCV. My code does its work and gets the job done, but I'm wondering if there's a 'better' way to do this. I hope I can get some tips on how to structure or approach this task.

See my full code [1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjbQDEh-nyvYVIyZW9Ba1Nqd0E) and [2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjbQDEh-nyvMHdfM2hxRDNSMUU).

```
while True:
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    persons = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in persons:

        cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x + w,y + h),(0, 255, 255),2)
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        rescaling_the_face = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))

        prophecy = model.predict(rescaling_the_face)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 255), 2)

        if prophecy[1]<400:
           cv2.putText(im,'%s' % (names[prophecy[0]]),(x + 10, (y + 22) + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.5,(20,205,20), 2)

        else:
          cv2.putText(im,'STRANGE_PERSON',(x + 10, (y + 22) + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.5,(65,65, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('OpenCV Face Recognition -  esc to close', im)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)

if key == 27:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes only:

Instead of

```
(_, im) = webcam.read()
```

is more common not to use parentheses:

```
_, im = webcam.read()
```

(and similarly in other places of your code).

---

Too many blank lines. In the PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code repeatedly occurs the word "sparingly" for the [Blank Lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) usage.

---

(Correcting English only):

Instead of

```
print("Webcam is open? ", webcam.isOpened())
```

use

```
print("Is the webcam open? ", webcam.isOpened())
```

---

Magic numbers in your code, as in this statement

```
if key == 27:
```

Why not use names for such constants, e. g.

```
ESC_KEY = 27               # Near the start of your code
...
...
if key == ESC_KEY:
```